# What encoding format is this?

Tags: language-agnostic, encoding, decoding

I'm trying to edit a (slightly) proprietary format and within one of the files it will encode a connection string.

I have a way to encode my own data with it, so I can reverse engineer it a bit.

```
ABC123"/3
```

will encode to

```
rijcmlqXxEeLA4tSspHg5XfWJiq4w==
```

and

```
AB120";2
```

encodes to

```
rijcmlqiF3LjnFJnYfEi2WvcSoPSg==
```

Is this a known encoding format? I've tried Base64 and it didn't produce anything useful.

Comment: It could be anything, known hash algorithm, salted hash, folded hash, CRC with `rijcmlq...==` surrounding it. There are many ways to make a cipher which is merely hard to penetrate. NSA folk probably have machines that can crack known-plaintext ciphers without blinking, but I can create something bothersomely complex to you (or me) in a line of Perl.

Comment: Cannot be a hash - the plaintext connection string is kinda necessary to connect. More likely, a reversible encryption. Who knows which one. :)

Probably some reverse engineering of the code is in order. Looking through the list of dependencies might provide a clue.

Answer (score 3):

Probably encryption followed by Base64. Many apps encrypt their connection strings.

Comment: Encryption is a safe bet, encryption algorithms do not necessarily map completely to a printable charset, thus the need to Base64 encode it (which is evident from the == suffix). Another alternative is to use a different base type algorithm, like Base32

Answer (score 0):

Write a program that converts both to binary.  Scan for similarities that way.

It will be impossible to see patterns that are not exactly 8 bits in ascii.

Comment: One similarity is that `rijcmlq` begins every encoded string. It seems to be a signature of some sort

Comment: Rijndael (also known as AES) is a pretty well-known, widely implemented symmetric cypher. It does not produce a signature by itself though; it could be so that a Rijndael-encrypted block is prepended with a header of some kind.